# Sorting an Object[][] in Java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement my leaderboard table for a mini-game I've written.

As of now I can read, decrypt, write and encrypt the `Object[][]` as well as display it in a `JTable`.

My problem now is, that I can't sort the `Object[][]` table which looks like:

> Name, Score
>
> John, 62
>
> Jane, 45
>
> Jona, 79

Just sorting the `JTable` doesn't do the trick for me since I have to access the written file externally and need the data sorted correctly in order to make it work correctly.

Comment: any reason why you are using array of Object instead class?

Comment: Are you storing your data as `arr[0][0] = "John"; arr[0][1] = 62;` ?

Comment: Have you looked at  `Arrays.sort` method?